# cmake find_path not working as expected

Tags: cmake

I have the following CMake script, it **works**:

```
find_path(
  GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES "GLES2/gl2.h"
  PATHS "${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH}/include")
```

But this one returns a `-NOTFOUND`:

```
find_path(
  GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES "gl2.h"
  PATHS "${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH}/include/GLES2")
```

Why? Any idea?

Comment: So, both codes are not working? Do you actually have a file `${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH}/include/GLES2/gl2.h`? (You may output that path with `message()` command for see result of dereferencing). Do you use cross-compiling?

Comment: No, the first code is working. Not the second code ! It is why it looks strange ?

Comment: Yes, this looks strange. And what is the result of the search in the first(successfull) case?

Comment: I agree with Tsyvarev, both commands should work if the file is present (although the second will return a different path than the first). We will need more information to help you here: Please put together [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, the exact output produced by the first find might be helpful.

Comment: I'd guess, it is a problem with caching.

Comment: There is no more code, everything is included here into a FindGLES.cmake file.

I don't think it is caching related, because I start from a clean build and I delete all the variables manually (CMake GUI). Also, even if the .cmake file contains only the second find_path, it failed !

Comment: Please, provide **exact** content of variable `GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR` after the first (successfull) script. E.g., with `message("Result: ${GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR}")`. This may throw some light on the problem. No needs to be agressive: we want to resolve the problem too. This is common debugging procedure, when one checks many things which seems obvious.

Comment: Does `find_path(GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR  NAMES "GLES2/gl2.h")` also work? My guess is that CMake does find the header in the default paths. [`CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH.html) seems a strange choice as an additional search path since the variable contains a "list of directories specifying a search path for OS X frameworks used by the find_library(), find_package(), find_path(), and find_file() commands." That said you could try to add `PATH_SUFFIXES "include/GLES2"` instead of `PATHS "${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH}/include/GLES2"`.

Answer (score 7):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

In your first case CMake just does find the header in the default paths.

[`CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH.html) seems a strange choice as an additional search path since the variable contains a "list of directories specifying a search path for OS X frameworks used by the find_library(), find_package(), find_path(), and find_file() commands."

I've given your example an try on my Ubuntu distribution and I could reproduce your problem with the flowing test:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(FindGL2)

unset(GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR CACHE)
find_path(
    GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES "GLES2/gl2.h"
    PATHS "${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH}/include"
)
message(STATUS "GLES2/gl2.h => ${GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR}")

unset(GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR CACHE)
find_path(
    GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES "gl2.h"
    PATHS "${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH}/include/GLES2"
)
message(STATUS "gl2.h => ${GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

Gives

```
-- GLES2/gl2.h => /usr/include
-- gl2.h => GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

**Solution**

Use `PATH_SUFFIXES "include/GLES2"` or just `PATH_SUFFIXES "GLES2"` instead:

```
find_path(
    GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES "gl2.h"
    PATH_SUFFIXES "GLES2"
)
message(STATUS "gl2.h => ${GLES_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

Does give:

```
-- gl2.h => /usr/include/GLES2
```

Comment: Great explanation. Its a little bit counter intuitive but this totally fixed my issue.

Comment: @Florian I have the opposite issue to that of the OP and I already use `PATH_SUFFIXES`. What confuses me is why `#include <GLES2/gl2.h>` works if the include path in the Ninja file is set to e.g. `"C:\sdk\GL\include\GLES2\"`. BTW. I use VS Code and Visual Studio. What I basically do is I look for the existence of the header in my find package modules and set that as the respective variable. All I want to do is to set the root include directory in the include search path e.g. `"C:\sdk\GL\include\"`

Comment: I found the reason why the second case wasn't working but the rest of the question stands as it is.